# My break code doesn't break my code. I don't understand where is the mistake

Tags: c

Program will run until '-1' is given as input. But it seems that '`if` condition/ / '`break` inside `if`' condition is not working.

```
int main() {
    int total= 0;
    int i;
    int numb;
    
    for (i = 0 ; true;i++)  /*'break' inside if condition not working*/ 
    {
        printf("enter the number: (press -1 to exit)");
        scanf("%d",&numb);
        
        if (numb== -1) 
        {
            break;
        }
        
        total+= numb;
    }
    
    printf("%d",total);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "my code is not working!" is not a useful problem description.  If your car doesn't work, do you call up a repair shop, say, "My car isn't working! I'm waiting for you to fix it!" and then hang up?  Just how much help do you think you'd get if you did that?  Well, that's what you just did here.

Comment: Works fine https://godbolt.org/z/rzvazvrM6

Comment: 1. `int main(void)` not `int main()`

Comment: You don't use `i` for anything... replace with `for (;;) { /*...break...*/ }`

Comment: You have commented out the for loop, there is nothing to "break" from.  You can only break from a for, while or switch.  Here you have neither.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf()` may *fail*.
When it fails once, if it's inside a loop, it will fail forever (for the same reason).

so check that it didn't fail

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int numb, total = 0;
    for (;;) {
        printf("enter the number: (press -1 to exit) ");
        fflush(stdout); // force output for line-oriented devices
        if (scanf("%d", &numb) != 1) {
            //scanf failed
            fprintf(stderr, "scanf() failed.\n");
            break;
        }
        if (numb == -1) break;
        total += numb;
    }
    printf("%d\n", total);
}
```